# Getting stack overflow exception only on mac (not windows) in non-recursive code when executing large Entity Framework query

Tags: c#, .net, macos, entity-framework-core, stack-overflow

I have a dotnet 6 application that is fetching a large amount of data programmatically from a sql server database using entity framework core.

In the past we had performance issues with making many different round trips to the database, so I am trying to get as much data as possible from any given execution of a query.

So what I am doing is taking a set of relationship ids and a set of time windows (a start `DateTimeOffset` and an end `DateTimeOffset`) for each relationship id, and building a large query that will get all of the data at once.

I initialize a "BaseQuery" so I don't have to select the fields I want over and over again as a property of this class, so it looks like:

```
public class DataService
    private readonly DbContext Db;
    private readonly IQueryable<DataValue> ValueBaseQuery;
    public DataService(
        DbContext db)
    {
        Db = db;
        ValueBaseQuery = (from v in Db.Values
                          select new DataValue
                          {
                              Id = v.Id,
                              Value = v.Value,
                              Timestamp = v.Timestamp
                          });
    }
```

The query method looks something like this:

```
public async Task<List<DataValue>> GetDataValuesAsync(
    Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<TimeWindow>> relationshipIdToTimeWindowsMap)
{
    // Initialize essentially an empty query that we will add to with unions programmatically below
    var fullQuery = ValueBaseQuery
        .Where(av => false);

    foreach (var kvp in relationshipIdToTimeWindowsMap)
    {
        foreach (var timeWindow in kvp.Value)
        {
            // Build an IQueryable for the given relationship Id in the given time window
            var localQuery = ValueBaseQuery
                .Where(v => v.RelationshipId == kvp.Key
                    && v.Timestamp > timeWindow.Start
                    && v.Timestamp <= timeWindow.End);

            // Add the IQueryable for this id and time window to our overall query via a Union
            fullQuery = fullQuery.Union(localQuery);
        }
    }

    return await fullQuery.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

and a TimeWindow is just simply:

```
public class TimeWindow
{
    public DateTimeOffset Start { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset End { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I run this code on my windows machine I have no issues.  It works great with fantastic performance compared to the old way of getting each relationship id's values with a separate query.

However, when my co-worker runs this code on their Mac, they run into a stack overflow exception.  We are both on 64 bit machines, so I don't think the potential difference in stack size is the issue based on the architecture, though I could be wrong.

The stack trace of their exception goes on very long with a lot of repeated data, but basically it has:

```
Stack overflow.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.SelectExpression+TpcTableExpressionRemovingExpressionVisitor.Visit(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.ProjectionExpression.VisitChildren(System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.SelectExpression+TpcTableExpressionRemovingExpressionVisitor.Visit(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.SelectExpression.<VisitChildren>g__VisitList|121_0[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]](System.Collections.Generic.List`1<System.__Canon>, Boolean, Boolean ByRef, <>c__DisplayClass121_0 ByRef)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.SelectExpression.VisitChildren(System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.SelectExpression+TpcTableExpressionRemovingExpressionVisitor.Visit(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression)
```

which repeats itself many times, and then is followed by this long stack trace:

```
(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.UnionExpression.VisitChildren(System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.SelectExpression+TpcTableExpressionRemovingExpressionVisitor.Visit(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.SelectExpression.<VisitChildren>g__VisitList|121_0[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]](System.Collections.Generic.List`1<System.__Canon>, Boolean, Boolean ByRef, <>c__DisplayClass121_0 ByRef)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.SelectExpression.VisitChildren(System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.SelectExpression+TpcTableExpressionRemovingExpressionVisitor.Visit(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.SelectExpression.Prune()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SelectExpressionPruningExpressionVisitor.Visit(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryTranslationPostprocessor.Process(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Query.Internal.SqlServerQueryTranslationPostprocessor.Process(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]](System.Linq.Expressions.Expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]](System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, Boolean)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]](Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IDatabase, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IModel, Boolean)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler+<>c__DisplayClass12_0`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].<ExecuteAsync>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]](System.Object, System.Func`1<System.Func`2<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryContext,System.__Canon>>)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]](System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]](System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].GetAsyncEnumerator(System.Threading.CancellationToken)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredCancelableAsyncEnumerable`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].GetAsyncEnumerator()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions+<ToListAsync>d__65`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions+<ToListAsync>d__65`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=7.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]](<ToListAsync>d__65`1<System.__Canon> ByRef)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].Start[[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions+<ToListAsync>d__65`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=7.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]](<ToListAsync>d__65`1<System.__Canon> ByRef)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]](System.Linq.IQueryable`1<System.__Canon>, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
   at Insights.Data.Services.Extensions.QueryExtensions+<ExecuteAsync>d__0`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]](System.__Canon ByRef)
   at Insights.Data.Services.Extensions.QueryExtensions.ExecuteAsync[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]](System.Linq.IQueryable`1<System.__Canon>, Serilog.ILogger)
   at Insights.Data.Services.SourceTypes.DataDogService+<GetMetricDataAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]](System.__Canon ByRef)
   at Insights.Data.Services.SourceTypes.DataDogService.GetMetricDataAsync(System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<Int32,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<Insights.Data.Sql.Models.TimeWindow>>)
   at Insights.Data.Services.Calculations.MetricDataService+<GetDataDogDataAsync>d__46.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]](System.__Canon ByRef)
   at Insights.Data.Services.Calculations.MetricDataService.GetDataDogDataAsync(System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<Insights.Data.Sql.EFModels.Calculation,Insights.Data.Sql.EFModels.CalculationField>, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<Int32,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<Insights.Data.Sql.Models.TimeWindow>>)
   at Insights.Data.Services.Calculations.MetricDataService.<GetMetricDataAsync>b__17_0(System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2<Insights.Data.Sql.Models.FieldSourceType,System.ValueTuple`2<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<Insights.Data.Sql.EFModels.Calculation,Insights.Data.Sql.EFModels.CalculationField>,System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<Int32,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<Insights.Data.Sql.Models.TimeWindow>>>>)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectEnumerableIterator`2[[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[[Insights.Data.Sql.Models.FieldSourceType, Insights.Data.Sql, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[System.ValueTuple`2[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WhenAll[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<System.__Canon>>)
   at Insights.Data.Services.Calculations.MetricDataService+<GetMetricDataAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]](System.__Canon ByRef)
   at Insights.Data.Services.Calculations.MetricDataService.GetMetricDataAsync(System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<Insights.Data.Sql.EFModels.Calculation,Insights.Data.Sql.EFModels.CalculationField>, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<Insights.Data.Sql.EFModels.Calculation,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<Insights.Data.Sql.Models.TimeWindow>>)
   at Insights.Data.Services.Calculations.MetricDataService+<GetMetricDataAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachineBox, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].SetExistingTaskResult(System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<System.__Canon>, System.__Canon)
   at Insights.Data.Services.Calculations.CalculationService+<GetFieldsMappedToCalculationsAsync>d__22.MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachineBox, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].SetExistingTaskResult(System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<System.__Canon>, System.__Canon)
   at Insights.Data.Services.Calculations.CalculationService+<GetFieldsAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachineBox, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].SetExistingTaskResult(System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<System.__Canon>, System.__Canon)
   at Insights.Data.Services.Extensions.QueryExtensions+<ExecuteAsync>d__0`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachineBox, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].SetExistingTaskResult(System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<System.__Canon>, System.__Canon)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions+<ToListAsync>d__65`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions+<ToListAsync>d__65`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=7.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachineBox, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].SetExistingTaskResult(System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Boolean>, Boolean)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1+AsyncEnumerator+<MoveNextAsync>d__20[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1+AsyncEnumerator+<MoveNextAsync>d__20[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=7.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachineBox, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].SetExistingTaskResult(System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Boolean>, Boolean)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy+<ExecuteAsync>d__30`2[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy+<ExecuteAsync>d__30`2[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=7.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachineBox, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].TrySetResult(System.__Canon)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy+<ExecuteImplementationAsync>d__31`2[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy+<ExecuteImplementationAsync>d__31`2[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=7.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachineBox, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(System.Object)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy+<>c__DisplayClass30_0`2+<<ExecuteAsync>b__0>d[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy+<>c__DisplayClass30_0`2+<<ExecuteAsync>b__0>d[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=7.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachineBox, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].SetExistingTaskResult(System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Boolean>, Boolean)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1+AsyncEnumerator+<InitializeReaderAsync>d__21[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1+AsyncEnumerator+<InitializeReaderAsync>d__21[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=7.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachineBox, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].TrySetResult(System.__Canon)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand+<ExecuteReaderAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand+<ExecuteReaderAsync>d__19, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=7.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachineBox, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishSlow(Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef, System.Threading.Thread)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.TryExecuteTaskInline(System.Threading.Tasks.Task, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskContinuation.InlineIfPossibleOrElseQueue(System.Threading.Tasks.Task, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinueWithTaskContinuation.Run(System.Threading.Tasks.Task, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].TrySetResult(System.__Canon)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.UnwrapPromise`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].TrySetFromTask(System.Threading.Tasks.Task, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.UnwrapPromise`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].ProcessInnerTask(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishSlow(Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef, System.Threading.Thread)
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading.PortableThreadPool+WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()
   at System.Threading.Thread.StartCallback()
```

Does anyone have any idea why this code, given a finite selection of relationship ids and time windows associated with them, would be triggering a stack overflow only on mac and not on windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else has this issue in the future and stumbles upon this question I asked, I was able to solve the issue.

It seems from what I can tell that despite being 64 bit, my co-worker's mac gets assigned a smaller stack size than my 64 bit windows machine.

I was able to get the problem to go away by limiting the number of unions that get performed in the query.  I initialize a counter at the start, and each time I add a union I add to the counter.  I found for one operation I was making over 300 unions.  This worked without issue on Windows machines and had great performance, but on the mac caused the stack overflow.  When I limited it to 100 and told it to execute the query one it reached 100 and then start over and add to the end results, the problem went away.

So it seems something with the way entity framework converts these union statements into a final query involves a lot of stack memory, and when doing several hundred unions, machines that get assigned a smaller stack size can overflow.